# When can we guarantee the existence of an entire function with specified values at the integers?

Tags: complex-analysis, interpolation, maximum-principle

[Carlson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlson%27s_theorem) is a uniqueness theorem that states (loosely) that if an entire function $f(z)$ of a complex variable takes on values $f_n$ at the integers $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then any other entire function that takes on the same values $f_n$ at the integers must behave very differently from $f(z)$ as $|z| \to \infty$.

Carlson's theorem only discusses uniqueness, but I'm wondering about the flip side, existence.

1. Given a double-sided sequence $f_n \in \mathbb{C}$, is there always an entire interpolating function that takes on those values at the integers? What if we place restrictions on the sequence $f_n$ (e.g. if we assume that it's bounded, or falls off as $n \to \pm\infty$)?
2. If we can guarantee the existence of such an entire interpolating function, then (assuming a sufficiently slowly growing sequence $f_n$) can we bound the asymptotic growth of the function? If so, then together with Carlson's theorem, that would guarantee that (for a sufficiently slowly growing sequence $f_n$) there is a unique slowly-growing entire interpolating function.

For question #1, one possible construction would be to take an entire basis function like $g(z) = \frac{\sin(z)}{z}$ and then form the infinite linear combination $\sum \limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f_n\, g(z - n)$. I believe that $f_n$ would need to fall off faster than $1/\log(n)$ for large $n$ in order for this series to converge on the real axis, but since this choice of $g(z)$ grows quickly in the imaginary direction, $f_n$ might need to fall off much faster in order to ensure convergence off the real axis. We could modulate the basis function $g(z)$ by something like $\exp \left( -z^2 \right)$ to improve convergence in the real direction, but that would make it worse in the imaginary direction (and vice versa for $\exp \left(z^2 \right)$).

Comment: I believe the answer to $(1)$ is yes, by iterating the following fact: for any $\epsilon>0$, any $r>0$, and any finite function $p: \{z_1,...,z_n\}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ such that every $z_i$ with $p(z_i)\not=0$ has $\vert z_i\vert>r$, there is an entire function $g$ such that $g(z_i)=p(z_i)$ for each $1\le i\le n$ and $\vert g(x)\vert<\epsilon$ whenever $\vert x\vert<r$. This lets us build the desired $f$ as a "quickly converging" sum of approximating $g$s, which I think makes $f$ entire as well.

Comment: in general given a discrete sequence of complex numbers (eg integers), an order $n_k \ge 0$ for each $a_k$ in the sequence and any $n_k+1$ values for each $a_k$, one can find an entire function $f$ which takes the given values up to order $n_k$ at $a_k$ (this meaning, $f(a_k), f'(a_k),...f^{(n_k)}(a_k)$ are the given $n_k+1$ numbers); this is a fairly easy interpolation theorem that generalizes Weierstrass factorization; I think Carlson theorem refers to functions of exponential type which is a very different (and well developed) theory than general entire functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_n$ be a secuence of values. By Wierstrass Factorization Theorem we can build a function $g(z)$ such that it has zeros of order one at the integers. Let $g_n=(g(z)/(z-n))|_{z=n}$. By Mittag-Leffler's theorem you can build now a function $f(z)$ such that $f$ has at any integer $n$ such that $f_n\neq 0$ a pole of order one and residue $f_n/g_n$ (and such that these are all it's poles). Therefore, $f(z)g(z)$ takes the desired values $f_n$ at the integers. Note that this construction also holds with the requirement that the values $f_n$ must be taken on a discrete subset of $\mathbb{C}$. As you can see, at the start of the construction we could multiply $g$ by any $e^{h(z)}$, with $h$ holomorphic, and then follow the process to get a distinct function which would be also a solution of the problem, so I believe there may be functions taking the arbitrary values $f_n$ which are not of exponential type.

Comment: Well, if the sequence $f_n$ itself grows faster than exponentially, then clearly any interpolating function can't be of exponential type, right?

Comment: Also, a tiny nitpick: I believe that the function $f(z)$ that you construct with Mittag-Leffler shouldn't have a pole at every integer, but instead at every integer with $f_n \neq 0$. If $f_n \equiv 0$, then you can just use $g(z)$ itself as your solution.

Comment: About your first comment, I was having in mind the case in which $f_n$ is decreasing, but the situation that you propose also would warranty that the resulting function can't be of exponential type. About your second comment, that's a good observation, however there is no harm since a function with a pole of order one and residue $0$ is an analytic function, but taking the $f_n=0$ separately is certainly better to avoid any confusion.

Comment: I believe that strictly speaking, a function with a pole of order one can't have residue 0 at that pole. If it's analytic then it can't have a pole at all. But I take your point, it's just a semantic quibble.

Comment: Yeah, to speak of a function with a pole of order one and residue zero was my convention just to make no further changes to the proof haha, but I'll add an edit, thanks